# Ruby on Rails Segmentation fault on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, openssl

```
$ rails new rails_example
```

...

```
run  bundle install
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/openssl/buffering.rb:238: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352) [x86_64-linux]

Aborted (core dumped)
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
```

I should have kept track of the things I've tried. The most recent ones were:

```
gem install bundler
gem pristine --all
```

Ubuntu 12.04, ruby 1.8.7, rails 3.2.4.rc1

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: @MurifoX same error but now I get more debug information that ends with "You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries."

Comment: @user1476028 did you do `aptitude install ruby libopenssl-ruby ruby1.8-dev` to install dependent library

Answer (score 0):

There's not a whole lot to go off of but hopefully you're using a ruby manager (RVM or rbenv with ruby-build) to install rubies and not via apt-get.  Using Rails 3.2 with Ruby 1.8.7 is simply not a good idea.

I put together a laundry list of steps I used to build a Rails development setup on Ubuntu 12.04.  Using rbenv, I install ruby 1.8.7, 1.9.2, and 1.9.3 alongside each other and run Rails just fine.  You can use RVM just the same - your choice.  Maybe this can help you clear some things up.  Be sure to check out the section "Install common libraries"...maybe you missed something there.

https://gist.github.com/2706272

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the following steps:

1. Check the version of the ruby and gem binaries actually executed:

   ```
   $ which ruby
   /usr/bin/ruby

   $ which gem
   /usr/bin/gem
   ```
2. Usually these are links to the actual executables. To check the linked executables:

   ```
   $ ls -o /usr/bin/gem
   lrwxrwxrwx 1 root 21 Dec 11 10:14 /usr/bin/gem -> /etc/alternatives/gem
   $ ls -o /etc/alternatives/gem
   lrwxrwxrwx 1 root 17 Dec 11 11:38 /etc/alternatives/gem -> /usr/bin/gem1.9.3
   $ ls -o /usr/bin/gem1.9.3
   lrwxrwxrwx 1 root 8 Nov 27 02:48 /usr/bin/gem1.9.3 -> gem1.9.1
   $ ls -o /usr/bin/gem1.9.1
   -rwxr-xr-x 1 root 547 Nov 27 02:50 /usr/bin/gem1.9.1
   ```

   In this case, the binary actually executed is /usr/bin/gem1.9.1, which is green (on my screen). Do the same for **ruby**
3. Use the ln (link) utility to link /etc/alternatives/gem to /usr/bin/gem1.9.3 if you do not see the above configuration. Refer to the manpage for ln utility.

Cheers